# reCAPTCHA inline invisible not showing Privacy and Terms links

Tags: recaptcha

I'm trying to add reCAPTCHA invisible/inline into my page and for some reason that I can't figure out why the Privacy and Terns links have on their CSS `display: none`.

This is what it looks like:

[reCaptcha with hidden links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gFOp.png)

Inspecting the code I can see this:

```css
.rc-anchor-invisible-text .rc-anchor-pt a:link {
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

And this is what the embed looks like:

```html
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit&isolated=true"></script>
  <script>
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('my-recaptcha', {
          sitekey : '<SITE_KEY>',
          badge: 'inline',
          size: 'invisible'
        });
      };
  </script>
  <form>
  <div id="my-recaptcha"></div>
```

They appear correctly if I change the `badge` property but are hidden when it's `inline`. Any idea on how to make them appear again?